# Xml Parsing NSString to NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml-parsing

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
}
```

In this the value in string I got is "1000" from the xml. I want to set this value to a NSInteger variable "count" . How can i set that ?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string is human readable number (in your case "1000" is), then ...

This returns an NSInteger:

```
[someString integerValue];
```